# Create a HOC (higher order component) for authentication in Next.js

Tags: node.js, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering, higher-order-components

So I'm creating authentication logic in my Next.js app. I created `/api/auth/login` page where I handle request and if user's data is good, I'm creating a `httpOnly` cookie with JWT token and returning some data to frontend. That part works fine but I need some way to protect some pages so only the logged users can access them and I have problem with creating a HOC for that.

The best way I saw is to use `getInitialProps` but on Next.js site it says that I shouldn't use it anymore, so I thought about using `getServerSideProps` but that doesn't work either or I'm probably doing something wrong.

This is my HOC code:
(cookie are stored under `userToken` name)

```
import React from 'react';
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const RequireAuthentication = (WrappedComponent) => {

  return WrappedComponent;
};


export async function getServerSideProps({req,res}) {
  const token = req.cookies.userToken || null;

// no token so i take user  to login page
  if (!token) {
      res.statusCode = 302;
      res.setHeader('Location', '/admin/login')
      return {props: {}}
  } else {
    // we have token so i return nothing without changing location
       return;
     }
}
export default RequireAuthentication;
```

If you have any other ideas how to handle auth in Next.js with cookies I would be grateful for help because I'm new to the server side rendering react/auth.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should separate and extract your authentication logic from `getServerSideProps` into a re-usable higher-order function.

For instance, you could have the following function that would accept another function (your `getServerSideProps`), and would redirect to your login page if the `userToken` isn't set.

```js
export function requireAuthentication(gssp) {
    return async (context) => {
        const { req, res } = context;
        const token = req.cookies.userToken;

        if (!token) {
            // Redirect to login page
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/admin/login',
                    statusCode: 302
                }
            };
        }

        return await gssp(context); // Continue on to call `getServerSideProps` logic
    }
}
```

You would then use it in your page by wrapping the `getServerSideProps` function.

```js
// pages/index.js (or some other page)

export const getServerSideProps = requireAuthentication(context => {
    // Your normal `getServerSideProps` code here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Although I have another problem, i can't get cookies in "getServerSideProps", i tried with req.cokies.userToken, with npm packages like nookies or cookie and nothing is working. I get the context object but when i access req.cookies a get and empty object event if i see that cookie on the browser

Comment: i didn't get this issue before because i didn't get so far with my solution so i think it's related to this

Comment: Okay, i even don't have the cookie object in my req.headers co i just start a new thread because im not sure if this is related to your answer, but thank you very much for help!

Comment: The HOC will just pass what's sent to it so shouldn't be an issue in itself. I've tested it locally, and I can see cookies being passed in `req.headers.cookie` inside the HOC.

Comment: This seems to be a nice approach for dynamic pages, dunno how to make it work for static pages (using getStaticProps).
Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're using static pages the authentication needs to happen on the client-side. `getStaticProps` runs at build time, and has no access to request-specific information like cookies. That being said, you could create some kind of custom hook (to be re-used) to deal with it on the client-side.

Comment: @juliomalves can you add ts version? i'm unable to type `gssp`? i got `context: GetServerSidePropsContext` working well but don't know how to type `gssp`. i went with `any`. furthermore, i get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`, how do i solve it?

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Typing `gssp` as `requireAuthentication(gssp: GetServerSideProps)` works for me. Regarding the error you're getting, you may want to create a new question for that as I don't think it's related to this question.

Comment: @juliomalves it was an error bcz i wasn't wrapping `ironSessionSsr` so when i did that, it worked but typing `gssp` as `GetServerSideProps` doesn't work for me, sadly :(

Comment: @deadcoder0904 You may want to create a new question for the typing issue you're having.

Comment: @juliomalves i would've but it isn't a significant of a problem. using `any` for now :)

Comment: is there a way to use this approach if I don't need to call getServerSideProps from the protected page?

Comment: @procul If you're not using `getServerSideProps` is the authentication happening on the client then? For that you can have a look at the client-side solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659746/1870780.

Comment: The authentication is still happening on the the server-side; however, I don't need to add additional server-side data fetching for some of the protected pages. The approach above seems to be a higher-order function for the gssp for the page, which means that it can't really be used for a page unless it has some some additional server-side fethching? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @procul You don't have to add any other server-side fetching if you don't want to. You could remove the `gssp` param from `requireAuthentication(gssp)` and refactor the HOC code accordingly if you don't want that. You'll probably still have to return an empty `props` object from the HOC though.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks!!

Comment: This is what I have been searching for 3 hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Based on Julio's answer, I made it work for `iron-session`:

```
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next'
import { withSessionSsr } from '@/utils/index'

export const withAuth = (gssp: any) => {
    return async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
        const { req } = context
        const user = req.session.user

        if (!user) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/',
                    statusCode: 302,
                },
            }
        }

        return await gssp(context)
    }
}

export const withAuthSsr = (handler: any) => withSessionSsr(withAuth(handler))
```

And then I use it like:

```
export const getServerSideProps = withAuthSsr((context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    return {
        props: {},
    }
})
```

My `withSessionSsr` function looks like:

```
import { GetServerSidePropsContext, GetServerSidePropsResult, NextApiHandler } from 'next'
import { withIronSessionApiRoute, withIronSessionSsr } from 'iron-session/next'
import { IronSessionOptions } from 'iron-session'

const IRON_OPTIONS: IronSessionOptions = {
    cookieName: process.env.IRON_COOKIE_NAME,
    password: process.env.IRON_PASSWORD,
    ttl: 60 * 2,
}

function withSessionRoute(handler: NextApiHandler) {
    return withIronSessionApiRoute(handler, IRON_OPTIONS)
}

// Theses types are compatible with InferGetStaticPropsType https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#typescript-use-getstaticprops
function withSessionSsr<P extends { [key: string]: unknown } = { [key: string]: unknown }>(
    handler: (
        context: GetServerSidePropsContext
    ) => GetServerSidePropsResult<P> | Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<P>>
) {
    return withIronSessionSsr(handler, IRON_OPTIONS)
}

export { withSessionRoute, withSessionSsr }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody using TRPC, and want to use a HOC for auth logic, this is our approach, notice that we only create helpers once:

```ts
import type {
  GetServerSidePropsContext,
  NextApiRequest,
  NextApiResponse,
} from "next";
import superjson from "superjson";
import type { DehydratedState } from "@tanstack/query-core";
import { createServerSideHelpers } from "@trpc/react-query/server";
import { appRouter } from "@/server/routers/_app";
import { createContext } from "@/server/context";

// Create a function to instantiate helpers
const createHelpers = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  return createServerSideHelpers({
    router: appRouter,
    ctx: await createContext({
      req: context.req as NextApiRequest,
      res: context.res as NextApiResponse,
    }),
    transformer: superjson,
  });
};
export const withAuth = (
  gssp: (
    context: GetServerSidePropsContext,
    helpers: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof createHelpers>>,
  ) => Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<{ [key: string]: any }>>,
) => {
  return async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    const helpers = await createHelpers(context);

    const { req } = context;
    const user = await helpers.users.sessionUser.fetch();

    if (!user) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: "/sign-in",
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }

    if (req.url?.includes("/admin")) {
      if (!user.admin) {
        return {
          notFound: true,
        };
      }
    }
    return gssp(context, helpers);
  };
};


// USAGE

 export const getServerSideProps = withAuth(async (_context, helpers) => {
  await helpers.campaigns.list.prefetch({});

  return {
    props: {
      trpcState: helpers.dehydrate(),
    },
  };
});
```