# How can I implement authentication with next-iron-session using getServerSideProps without including the same code on each page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, next.js

I am implementing authentication in my NextJS app using `next-iron-session`, currently using `getServerSideProps` method for that an it is working fine but I have to implement this in every page where I want to authenticate the user. I just want to implement it in HOC format or wrapper format so I don't have to rewrite this in every file. I am using the following code for that

```js
import { withIronSession } from "next-iron-session";

const user_home = (props) => {
  if (!user.isAuth) {
    router.push("/");
  }
  // ...some other layout stuff
};
export const getServerSideProps = withIronSession(
  async ({ req, res }) => {
    const user = req.session.get("user");
    if (!user) {
      return {
        props: { isAuth: false },
      };
    }
    return {
      props: { isAuth: true, user: user },
    };
  },
  {
    cookieName: "NEXT_EXAMPLE",
    cookieOptions: {
      secure: true,
    },
    password: process.env.APPLICATION_SECRET,
  }
);

export default user_home;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Creating a HOC (higher order component) for cookies in nextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66081052/creating-a-hoc-higher-order-component-for-cookies-in-nextjs)? Add the logic to a higher-order function and reuse it across your pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is a bit old but here is my solution, with [iron-session](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session) since `next-iron-session` has been deprecated.

Create a HOC like this

```
import { withIronSessionSsr } from "iron-session/next";
import { sessionOptions } from "./session";

const WithAuth = (gssp) =>
  withIronSessionSsr(async function (context) {
    const user = context.req.session.user;
    // you can check the user in your DB here 
    if (!user) {       
     return {
       redirect: {
         permanent: false,
         destination: "/login",
       },
     }
   }

   return await gssp(context);   
  }, sessionOptions);

export default WithAuth;
```

Then in your page

```
export const getServerSideProps = WithAuth(async function (context) {
  ...
  return {
    props: { user: context.req.session.user, ... },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can redirect from the server.

```
import { withIronSession } from "next-iron-session";

const user_home = (props) => {
 
  // ...some other layout stuff
};
export const getServerSideProps = withIronSession(
  async ({ req, res }) => {
    const user = req.session.get("user");
    if (!user) {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/login",
      },
    }
    return {
      props: { user: user },
    };
  },
  {
    cookieName: "NEXT_EXAMPLE",
    cookieOptions: {
      secure: true,
    },
    password: process.env.APPLICATION_SECRET,
  }
);

export default user_home;
```

Comment: I just want to shift that code in a particular file that I can reuse where I want to authenticate user, in the current scenario I have to add that validation code to every page I made to validate user.