# How to create HOC for auth in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

I want to create basic Next.js HOC for authentication. I searched but I didn't figure it out.

I have an admin page in my Next.js app. I want to fetch from `http://localhost:4000/user/me` and that URL returns my user. If user data returns, component must be rendered. If data didn't return, I want to redirect to the `/admin/login` page.

I tried this code but that didn't work. How can I solve this issue? Also can I use `useSWR` instead of `fetch`?

```
const withAuth = (Component, { data }) => {
  if (!data) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/admin/login",
      },
    };
  }
  return Component;
};

withAuth.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/user/me");
  const data = await response.json();
  return { data };
};

export default withAuth;
```

```
const AdminHome = () => {
  return ();
};
export default withAuth(AdminHome);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Creating a HOC (higher order component) for cookies in nextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088247/1870780)?

Comment: Actually, i seen this before but i didn't figured out. Do you know how can I use that code in my example?

Comment: Move both the fetch request and the redirect code into the higher-order function.

Comment: i did but it didnt work

Comment: You need to modify your code accordingly too to use the higher-order function on the `getServerSideProps` and not wrap the component itself.

Comment: Can you write the code as an example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

##### Server-side authentication

Based on the answer from [Create a HOC (higher order component) for authentication in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088247/1870780), you can create a re-usable higher-order function for the authentication logic.

If the user data isn't present it'll redirect to the login page. Otherwise, the function will continue on to call the wrapped `getServerSideProps` function, and will return the merged user data with the resulting props from the page.

```js
export function withAuth(gssp) {
    return async (context) => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/user/me');
        const data = await response.json();
        
        if (!data) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/admin/login'
                }
            };
        }

        const gsspData = await gssp(context); // Run `getServerSideProps` to get page-specific data
        
        // Pass page-specific props along with user data from `withAuth` to component
        return {
            props: {
                ...gsspData.props,
                data
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can then use it on the `AdminHome` page to wrap the `getServerSideProps` function.

```js
const AdminHome = ({ data }) => {
    return ();
};

export const getServerSideProps = withAuth(context => {
    // Your normal `getServerSideProps` code here
    return { props: {} };
});

export default AdminHome;
```

---

##### Client-side authentication

If you'd rather have the authentication done on the client, you can create a higher-order component that wraps the component you want to protect.

```js
const withAuth = (Component) => {
    const AuthenticatedComponent = () => {
        const router = useRouter();
        const [data, setData] = useState()

        useEffect(() => {
            const getUser = async () => {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/user/me');
                const userData = await response.json();
                if (!userData) {
                    router.push('/admin/login');
                } else {
                    setData(userData);
                }  
            };
            getUser();
        }, []);

        return !!data ? <Component data={data} /> : null; // Render whatever you want while the authentication occurs
    };

    return AuthenticatedComponent;
};
```

You can then use it to wrap the `AdminHome` component directly.

```js
const AdminHome = () => {
  return ();
};

export default withAuth(AdminHome);
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much. Thats really nice. I'm using client side rendering in admin component. How can i wrap this code using withAuth()

For example:

`const posts = useSWR("http://localhost:4000/post", (...args) =>
    fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())
  );`

Basically i want to protect whole admin component

Comment: In my example, `withAuth` is meant to run on the server as it's a wrapper for `getServerSideProps` - you can't use `useSWR` on server-side code. It's a React hook and can only be used on the client-side.

Comment: Yeah I know useSWR only be used for client-side. Therefore I need to protect whole admin component. If user try to access admin component i need to send him to admin/login page

Comment: Yes i need to client-side protection. User can't reach the whole page if not logged in. I need to redirect admin/login page

Comment: If you don't want the user to reach the page, wouldn't my approach done on the server-side be more suitable then? Or is there a reason you need the auth to happen on the client? If you do it client-side, the page will load and _then_ the user will be redirected.

Comment: I'm trying to do personal-blog page. My blog page side is already server-side rendering for seo purposes. But i need to do client-side rendering for admin side. Because i don't need seo here.

Comment: You can have the auth logic done on the server, and still do client-side rendering on the admin page, they're not mutually exclusive. Still, I can add a solution for client-side auth to my answer.

Comment: I tried your code and if user not logged in data is not coming but i can still reach the page. I need to wrap whole component in this way if user not logged in automatically redirect to admin/login page

Comment: That's not the expected behaviour. If user is not logged in, the app will redirect to the `/admin/login` page.

Comment: `export const getServerSideProps = withAuth(() => {
  async () => {
    const postsResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/post");
    const postsData = await postsResponse.json();
    return {
      props: {
        posts: postsData.data,
      },
    };
  };
});`

Here is the code still component is loading but only posts section is empty.

Comment: I tried your client-side code and still it didn't work. I think I didn't figured out. Again thank you so much for helping. I will try to do it again.

Comment: Wow, it's work. Thank you so much this really help to me

Comment: Making an additional request every time you need to check auth state, is not performance-wise. It should only check the client state, then let the other requests validate the token, which needs to be made anyway.

Comment: @juliomalves Hi, is it necessary to use both client and server side approach together? Which one is the better approach

Comment: @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol No, it's either one or the other. It depends on your requirements.

Comment: To handle `props` in client side add: `const AuthenticatedComponent = (props)...<Component {...props} />`

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the typescript version:

**withAuth.ts**

```
export function withAuth(gssp: GetServerSideProps): GetServerSideProps {
  return async (context) => {
    const { user } = (await getSession(context.req, context.res)) || {};

    if (!user) {
      return {
        redirect: { statusCode: 302, destination: "/" },
      };
    }

    const gsspData = await gssp(context);

    if (!("props" in gsspData)) {
      throw new Error("invalid getSSP result");
    }

    return {
      props: {
        ...gsspData.props,
        user,
      },
    };
  };
}
```

**Home.tsx**

```
export const getServerSideProps = withAuth(async (context) => {
  return { props: {} };
});
```