# How to prevent Next.js flash when visiting register page while being authenticated?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So let me give you a brief background. I am using Laravel Breeze with Next.js. Everything works perfectly fine, but there's a slight problem. When I am authenticated while being on the `/dashboard` page and I load the `/register` page, there is a flash of the `/register` page before the redirection back to the `/dashboard` page.

Something similar also happens when I visit the `/dashboard` page while not being authenticated. I have done something to alleviate the `/dashboard` flash by putting up logic to show a `loading...` text though. However, it still seems like the page should not even load and the redirect should happen to `/register` using some middleware.

**Dashboard.js**

```
import BasicLayout from "@/components/layouts/BasicLayout";
import { useAuth } from "../src/hooks/auth";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { logout, user } = useAuth({ middleware: "auth" });

  return (
    <>
      {!user && <p>loading...</p>}
      {user && 
        <>
            <p>{user?.name}</p>
            <button onClick={logout}>Sign out</button>
        </>
      }
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;

Dashboard.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
    return <BasicLayout>{page}</BasicLayout>;
  };
```

**useAuth() hook**

```
import axios from '@/src/lib/axios';
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import useSWR from 'swr'

export const useAuth = ({ middleware, redirectIfAuthenticated } = {}) => {
    const router = useRouter()

    const { data: user, error, mutate } = useSWR('/api/user', () =>
        axios
            .get('/api/user')
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status !== 409) throw error

                router.push('/verify-email')
            }),
    )

    const csrf = () => axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', { withCredentials: true })

    const register = async ({ setErrors, ...props }) => {
        await csrf()

        setErrors([])

        axios
            .post('/register', props)
            .then(() => mutate())
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error

                setErrors(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat())
            })
    }

    const login = async ({ setErrors, setStatus, ...props }) => {
        await csrf()

        setErrors([])
        setStatus(null)

        axios
            .post('/login', props)
            .then(() => mutate())
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error

                setErrors(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat())
            })
    }

    const forgotPassword = async ({ setErrors, setStatus, email }) => {
        await csrf()

        setErrors([])
        setStatus(null)

        axios
            .post('/forgot-password', { email })
            .then(response => setStatus(response.data.status))
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error

                setErrors(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat())
            })
    }

    const resetPassword = async ({ setErrors, setStatus, ...props }) => {
        await csrf()

        setErrors([])
        setStatus(null)

        axios
            .post('/reset-password', { token: router.query.token, ...props })
            .then(response => router.push('/login?reset=' + btoa(response.data.status)))
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error

                setErrors(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat())
            })
    }

    const resendEmailVerification = ({ setStatus }) => {
        axios
            .post('/email/verification-notification')
            .then(response => setStatus(response.data.status))
    }

    const logout = async () => {
        if (! error) {
            await axios
                .post('/logout')
                .then(() => mutate())
        }

        window.location.pathname = '/login'
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (middleware === 'guest' && redirectIfAuthenticated && user) router.push(redirectIfAuthenticated)
        if (middleware === 'auth' && error) logout()
    }, [user, error])

    return {
        user,
        register,
        login,
        forgotPassword,
        resetPassword,
        resendEmailVerification,
        logout,
    }
}
```

Comment: _"it still seems like the page should not even load and the redirect should happen to `/register` using some middleware"_ - because you're doing the redirect on the client-side, that will always occur. If you want the page to not even load then you'll need to move the authentication check to the server-side by using `getServerSideProps`, and have the redirect there instead.

Comment: `getServerSideProps` is meant for a page I suppose. My API call for checking user authentication is in a hook called `useAuth()`. Any help in the right direction will be appreciate. Sorry, a Next newbie here.

Comment: It is meant for a page, and the auth check would have to be moved there (from the `useAuth` hook, which runs on the client) if you don't want the page to even load. You may find the answer to [How to create HOC for auth in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325619/how-to-create-hoc-for-auth-in-next-js) useful, as it provides a solution for both client-side (similar to what you currently have, using a HOC instead of a hook) and server-side authentication (what I am suggesting).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will take a look. I am trying to visually avoid a flash, maybe I can look into more client side approaches rather than doing away with my useAuth() hook which works well already. Looking to solve it using the simplest way possible first.

Comment: Avoiding the flash on the client-side can only be done by displaying a loading state, like you have already done.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes. I was researching using getServerSideProps but my authentication is using Laravel Sanctum using cookies stored on the browser, so I am not sure how it would even work. The server that renders the page wouldn't have access to the session information.

Comment: @AliGajani any success? Anyways, could you please provide your own experience as an answer here for people who maybe faced same issue?