# Is it possible to send client-side (browser) cookie to the server-side in next.js so that it can be used in the server-side?

Tags: laravel, next.js

I am using Next.js for the front end and Laravel (sanctum) for the back end.

Since I use Sanctum for SPA authentication, it stores cookies in the browser. These cookies authenticate the user and send requests to protected API endpoints. I am using [breeze-next](https://github.com/laravel/breeze-next) starter kit; it provides a `useAuth` hook to do all authentication tasks and get authenticated user

it get the user by calling a protected endpoint `api/user`

`src/hooks/auth.js`

```
const { data:user, error, mutate } = useSWR("/api/user", () =>
    axios
      .get("/api/user")
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status !== 409) throw error;
        router.push("/verify-email");
      })
      .finally(function () {
        setUserLoading(false)
      })
  );
```

and the axios is slightly modified to send the stored cookies with the request for accessing the protected route.

`src/lib/axios.js`

```
import Axios from "axios";

const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
  headers: {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  },
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default axios;
```

So `useAuth` works in client-side only. Using it in server-side gives error like these
`Error: (0 , _hooks_auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useAuth) is not a function`

Now the problem I want to solve is to prevent protected routes in the front-end. In laravel with plain HTML/CSS, accessing it will redirect to the login page. I want to do something like that in next.js directly from the server side, not on the client side. I have considered using `useEffect` and checking whether the user is authenticated or not and then using `window.location.replace`. But it will take some time to get the user data and decide. Meantime, it will show the protected route. But I want to prevent it and decide it from the server. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64662486/13006156), but `useAuth` cannot be used on the server. So, I tried to send the client-side cookie to the server side and use it to call `api/user`. I used next.js middleware for this.

`middleware.js`

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request) {
    console.log(`=== ${request.url}`);
    // console.log(request)
    // console.log(request.headers)
    console.log(request.cookies.get('laravel_session'));
    console.log(request.cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
    console.log('=== -- ===');

    let response = NextResponse.next();
    response.cookies.set('XSRF-TOKEN', request.cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')?.value)
    // console.log(response);

    return response;
}

export const config = {
    // matcher: ['/admin/:path*'],
};
```

```
import dns from 'node:dns';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import axios from './axios';

export const getAuthenticatedUser = () => {
    dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first');

    axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/api/user`)
    // fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/api/user`, {
    //     credentials: 'include',
    //     method: 'GET',
    //     headers: {
    //         'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    //         'X-XSRF-Token': cookies().get('XSRF-TOKEN').value,
    //     },
    // })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

But it does not work. It gives `401`. I also checked the token received on the server, and it does not match the one stored in the browser.

Does anyone know any other alternative.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for next middleware https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware it can be used to redirect based on users logged in state.